# Unable to add the mat-divider to the mat-list-item

Tags: angular

I am using Angular Material for the first time and I need to add a divider under every item:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/bvdefs-g4gn6w?file=src%2Fexample%2Flist-sections-example.html,src%2Fexample%2Flist-sections-example.ts

I need to add the divider after every item but this is not working?
Is there a way to add the mat-divider below every item and it should be customizable I need full width and some places more customization on the width of the divider

````
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let folder of folders">
    <img
      matListItemAvatar
      src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg"
      alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu"
    />
    <div matListItemTitle>{{folder.name}}</div>
    <div matListItemLine>{{folder.updated | date}}</div>
    <div matListItemLine>{{folder.updated | date}}</div>
    <span matListItemMeta><mat-icon matListItemIcon>folder</mat-icon></span>
    <!-- Need a mat divider -->
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>```
````

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ? Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Added the Stackblitz link, the divider is not visible

Answer (score 2):

I think you are having the issue because you are trying to add the divider inside of your `mat-list-item`.  I tried just adding a normal `<hr />` and had no issues.  But the `<hr />` only took up the length of its parent.

Try adding the divider outside of your `<mat-list-item>`, like in the example below:

```
 <mat-list>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let folder of folders">
  <mat-list-item>
    <img
      matListItemAvatar
      src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg"
      alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu"
    />
    <div matListItemTitle>{{folder.name}}</div>
    <div matListItemLine>{{folder.updated | date}}</div>
    <div matListItemLine>{{folder.updated | date}}</div>
    <span matListItemMeta><mat-icon matListItemIcon>folder</mat-icon></span>
    <!-- Need a mat divider -->
    
  </mat-list-item>
  <!-- ADD THE DIVIDER HERE INSTEAD -->
  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
</ng-container>
</mat-list>
```

All I did was to add the `ngFor` to an `<ng-container>` and then moved the divider outside of the list.

It will still be after every item, because it is still inside the for loop, and now you can customise it however you want.